# Annoying error: Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I have following problem while working with Firebase:

Every thrid or fourth time I run my project I encounter following error message:

```
Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
```

Then I can temporarily solve the problem by running `pod deintegrate && pod install`. 
After restarting Xcode then it indexes again and then works for three builds and again throws that error. I tried all solutions I found in the other forums, but it only seems to be a temporary fix.

I tried the following:

- change 'Framework Search Paths' both for Debug and Release to start with `$(inherited)`, Result: **changed nothing**
- Removing all 'Framework Search Paths' and adding them again, Result: **changed nothing**
- run `pod update && pod install`, Result: **changed nothing** except creating a new error: `34 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64` which disappeared again after deintegrate and install
- add `pod 'Firebase/Core'` to the Podfile and run update and install, Result: **changed nothing**
- Deleting & reinstalling all pods, Result: **temporarily fixed the issue** but after some builds/runs of the project the same error presented itself again...
- run `pod deintegrate && pod install, Result: **temporarily fixed the issue** but after some builds/runs of the project the same error presented itself again...
- Deleting the DerivedData Folder and deleting the files inside, Result: **temporarily fixed the issue** but after some builds/runs of the project the same error presented itself again...

I really do not know what the issue could be, and I don't feel like running deintegrate and install every third time I run my app... (Jokes beside)

Here I found some *maybe interesting* console part, in previous builds (the three times it works) only the first line gets output.

```
2020-03-22 18:18:04.356534+0100 APPNAME[18415:4803927] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-03-22 18:18:04.762836+0100 APPNAME[18415:4803912] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800003] Registered an SDK that has already registered. Default flags will be overwritten. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-03-22 18:18:04.763111+0100 APPNAME[18415:4803912] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
```

There was no forum post that changed this, please share any idea that could solve this problem. I've been researching quite a bit now, but there seems to be no better fix than running `pod deintegrate && pod install` or clearing the derived data folder and restarting Xcode every time...

Comment: This could be the result of linking Firebase into multiple dynamic libraries and getting resulting indeterministic behavior depending upon which copy gets executed.

Comment: Ok, how could I solve that?

Comment: See discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5162

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but after adding `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`, the issue still appeared after some builds. It's really annoying...

Comment: As discussed there, that option makes no difference if your app is linking Firebase into its own dynamic frameworks.